# What exactly does Firebase Authentication Include?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was checking out [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and it said that it was free but I wanted to know how exactly it worked.I have my own database of users containing usernames and passwords against which I can do a SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username=username and password=password query and get a result back but i wanted to know if firebase authentication will help me in any way with this ? Maybe it could make it more secure ? If i do user firebase authentication,will it be storing my users data in the firebase database and if so will it still be a free plan or is that paid?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication fully manage user registration and/or login process of your application (even password reset process). You can view all of users data from Firebase Console.

This user data only have limited information attached to it, like email and password, and some additional information if that user account is connected with Google Authentication (like display photo, gender, etc).

But you can add your as many custom information / attribute as you want. The easiest way to do that is by saving those additional information into your Firebase Database. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926672/how-to-add-additional-information-to-firebase-auth) for more information.

Comment: So i would end up storing information in the firebase database for which i would be limited by the paid plans?

Comment: You also can save those information in your own place, like your MySql server. Just get the user id from Firebase Auth to be used as key to your own data storage.