# Firebase login and signup with username

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using AndroidHive's [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/) to learn how to use Firebase, I am starting to understand the methods and documentation well now - I realised that Firebase offers a signup/sign-in method with email and password, and that this piece of information is not stored in our database.

I would like to implement a system where when they sign up they provide their email,password and a username along with some other data and it all gets saved to the database. So that the user can then signin with their email or username. I found this article on stack which apparently is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151178/how-do-you-include-a-username-when-storing-email-and-password-using-firebase-ba) to this question I am asking - However, I do not fully understand this and how it links with my code below

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
});
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    generateUser(email, password)

    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
});
```

This is the method that is being called above.

```
public void generateUser(String username, String password)
{

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("users"); //users is a node in your Firebase Database.
User user = new User(username, password); //ObjectClass for Users
users.push().setValue(user);

}
```

Also: 
**User.class**

```
   public class User {

    String username;
    String password;

    public User() {
    //Empty Constructor For Firebase
    }


public User(String username, String password)
        {
        this.username = username; //Parameterized for Program-Inhouse objects.
        this.password = password;
        }

    //Getters and Setters
    public String getUsername()
    {
    return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
    this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
    return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
    this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah this worked thanks, I wasn't completely sure about the structure but this cleared things up

Comment: Also, I would recommend you to "encrypt" the password before sending it to the database. I would recommend you to soft encrypt them. Maybe try this: [140Encryptor](https://github.com/tanishqsh/140Encryptor/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks, Yes I've already created an encryption method in my class, I am getting an error with your code though, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoN3gxajFBUUhUX1E/view?usp=sharing are you sure the User constructor needs to be empty? Sorry I'm just thinking about pure java i'm new to firebase, also there is an error with push aswell cant resolve type, I've imported the database and added it to build gradle

Comment: Yes, you can have both Empty as well as Parameterized constructor. Empty constructor is important and must while reading data from Firebase. Check **Retrieving Data** section in Firebase Docs. 

Sorry for one little mistake, here we have to put both. Editing the above answer.

Comment: I still seem to have an error with push, any idea why?

Comment: @TerribleCoder

Please make this correction:
`FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getDatabase();`

Comment: As a matter of fact it doesnt work, push has the same error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoaEh6bDJyTUk0cVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got your problem. Make FirebaseDatabase a global variable and initialise it in onCreate. It requires a context at the point. Just take `FirebaseDatabase database;` before onCreate. And In, onCreate: initialise, `database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`. Don't initialise in method. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: @TerribleCoder check my new answer below

Comment: How to sign in with just the username and password later?

Answer (score 0):

Undo the addition of `.getDatabase();` first. 
This is not a native Firebase method, my mistake.

I got your problem.

Make FirebaseDatabase a global variable and initialise it in onCreate. It requires a context at the point.

Just take `FirebaseDatabase database;` before onCreate.

And In, onCreate: initialise, `database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`.

Don't initialise in method. I'll edit my previous answer soon.

Comment: Okay, if I use setValue without push it works, but I need user accounts to stack not delete once someone else signs up. The error is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoU09iSXFoWjFwaVU/view?usp=sharing. I also set the DB reference in OnCreaate at the top too

Comment: Hahah, what a lame mistake. Its `users.push().setValue();` Since its a method. **push** is essential, it generates time based keys.