# How to get UID and add user information with Firebase email/password authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase Email/password authentication for both signup and sign in. However during the Sign up process I would like to get the user UID and use that to create a new database in firebase with other user information like Name and phonenumber. I know its easier to get the UID with a login process, however is there a way to do this with signup, assuming sign up has been successful.  I am using android studio.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Because this topic has been covered a few times already. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151178/how-do-you-include-a-username-when-storing-email-and-password-using-firebase-ba/32151335#32151335) or probably quite a few of the [items in this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+%5Bfirebase-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+store+users).

Answer (score 4):

You can get the user information from the task returned by the completion listener:

```
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: uid=" + user.getUid());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I saw this in the documentation and I already tried using. however I am getting the error that firebase.auth not found. I had this error before and I fixed it so am wondering why its coming up again.

Comment: @PaulMpanga: Can you post the error?  The code runs successfully for me.

Comment: it worked, my User class was written weird. thanks!!

Comment: will i be able to add the `userid` in database inside `task.isSuccessful`? Example inside the if , do this `newStudent.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());`. The `newStudent` is a DatabaseReference will this work?

Comment: @PeterHaddad: Yes