# React+Firebase. Write to Database after Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently setting up Firebase for my React Native app. Authentication & basic writing/reading work fine. 
Though, I struggle to write data to the database right after the initial authentication because my "`signUp`" and "`writeUserData`" functions execute at the same time (and at this moment there is no `userId` yet).

Here is my code:

```
...

module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      result: '',
    })
  },

  signUp() {
    if (this.state.password === this.state.confirmPassword) {
      let {email, password} = this.state;
      firebaseApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(error => this.setState({result: error.message
      }));
      this.writeUserData(email);
    } else {
      this.setState({result: 'Passwords do not match.'})
    }
  },

  writeUserData(email) {
    let userId = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId + '/').set({
        info: {
          firstName: 'Jonas',
          email: email,
        },
        currentState: {
          currentDay: 0,
          currentSeries: 0,
        }
    });
  },
  render() {
...
```

I can't find any good documentation about this. Can someone give me a pointer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns Promise, you have to use it's `.then` for updating the user details, like this:

```
firebaseApp.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then( user => { 
    user.updateProfile({
        displayName: 'Jonas'
    });
    user.updateEmail(email);
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({result: error.message}));
```

Note also the [appropriate way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateEmail) to update user' email

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I agree. I my latest version of the code uses a `.then` method. It seems more appropriate & reliable than `onAuthStateChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution within Stack Overflow. Much easier than expected: [How do you include a username when storing email and password using Firebase (BaaS) in an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151178/how-do-you-include-a-username-when-storing-email-and-password-using-firebase-ba)

**EDIT**: I'm using now the `onAuthStateChanged`method instead.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if(user) {
        this.writeUserData(user.uid, user.email, this.state.firstName);
      }
    })
  },

  writeUserData(userId, email, firstName) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId + '/').set({
        info: {
          firstName: firstName,
          email: email,
        },
        currentState: {
          currentDay: 0,
          currentSeries: 0,
        }
    });
  },
```